# Deserializing Json string to C# Class object or DataSet. Which is more efficient?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using JSON.Net to deserialize a JSON string to object. My JSON string consists of huge data which can be loaded onto an array or dataset. Could someone please let me know which of the below appraoch is more efficient for the same.

```
var CSharpClassObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CSharpClass[]>(jsonString);
```

and

```
var dataSetObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a performance problem? Why don't you take some benchmarks and see which one is faster?

Comment: The `Stopwatch` class is a developer's best friend when trying to answer these types of questions. Spin up a simple console app and find that answer for yourself.

Comment: I tried using Ants Profiler to measure the performance but i'm not seeing much difference between them. Just wanted to reconfirm before finalizing any approach.

Comment: dataset will only be slightly larger in memory so a bit slower to load but it's not much. I prefer class as you have define properties and methods linked to the data.

Comment: If you've profiled it and there's not much difference, then use the one that is easier for you to use and maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datasets are generally inefficient due to the memory they require, as well as events, etc. They are really suited to RAD (Rapid Application Development) and not too much else. For your purposes (and probably most others) I would certainly suggest using a custom type.